# Git merge without globally setting username

Tags: git, merge

Is it possible to perform a `git merge` without having a globally set user.email/use.name?

I get the following fatal error preventing the merge:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident  <email> not allowed
```

In case of `git commit`, one can simply perform a commit without a global username/email by adding `--author 'Your Name <email>'`

`git commit -m 'my_funny_commit_comment' --author 'Your Name <email>'`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the email and password only for your current repository if you don't want to set it globally -

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email "you@example.com"
```

Although above approach is recommended, you can pass the parameters with `git commit` too

```
git -c "user.name=Your Name" -c "user.email=you@example.com" commit
```

Comment: I don't want the username to be stored on the current repository either. I would like it to get the username for each commit/merge. If I can somehow set it for my current session (console) only, that would be fine.

Comment: Try setting the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` environment variables in your console and see if that is per-session on your system.

Comment: setting `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and 'GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL' didn't help.

Comment: The `git -c configsetting` pattern offered in the second part of the answer was the perfect solution for me.